# Protractor- Add waiting time until cookie is set

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angular7

I am running angular tests using protractor and trying to set cookies but doesn't seem to work.
How can I add waiting until cookie is set?

```
  public async visit() {
    await navigateTo();
    return this.whenReady();
  }

export async function navigateTo() {
   browser.get('http://' + 'localhost' + ':4200');
   browser.manage().addCookie({ name: 'auth', value: 'true', path: '/', domain: 'localhost' });
   await browser.manage().getCookie('auth');
}
```

it always return null and cookie is not set.

Comment: `visit()` function is no properly declared. In javascript there isn't a `public` keyword.

Comment: it is typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Add `await` right before both `browser.get()` and `browser.manage().getCookie()` because they return a Promise.

```js
export const navigateTo = async () => {
   await browser.get('http://localhost:4200');
   await browser.manage().addCookie({ name: 'auth', value: 'true', path: '/', domain: 'localhost' });
   await browser.manage().getCookie('auth');
};
```

Comment: tried that as well but browser moves too fast. It doesn't wait for cookies to be added.

Comment: Could you post the code in which you call `navigateTo()`?